# Группировка с получением интервала строк

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте!
У меня таблица с полями 
TaskLetter, TaskType_ID
A1 1
A2 1
A3 1
A4 1
B5 2
B6 2
B7 2
B8 2
B9 2
B10 3
B11 3
B12 3
B13 3
B14 1
B15 1
B16 1
Мне надо получить
А1-А4 - 1
В5-В9 - 2
В10 - В13 - 3
В14 - В16 - 1
Как можно это сделать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT startrange + ' - ' + endrange as rng, task_id 
FROM (select min(task_letter) as startrange, max(task_letter) as endrange, task_id 
            FROM test  
            group BY substring(task_letter, 1, 1), task_id) a 
ORDER BY cast(substring(startrange, 2, len(startrange) - 1) AS int)
```

Comment: Не выдает интервала В14-В16, 
Весь вопрос именно в этом - если у меня TaskType_ID непоследовательный, а "сидит" с разрывами, А1-А4, В14-В16, то не дает правильного интервала. В результате должны быть видны два интервала для TaskType_ID = 1(в данном конкретном случае).